# How can I build a slider to increase font size across a dash app

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have tried to make my dash dashboard as accessible as possible across all users needs

I have tried to come up with a callback on the dash app which allows the user to have accessibility features and I am struggling with this one, changing the font size of text across the app. I have been able to have a slider and a call back which will change the text size

```
dcc.Slider(min=0, max=2, step=1, value=0, 
               marks={0: 'Regular',
                                          1: 'Large',
                                          2: 'Larger'},
                                   id='font-slider'),
```

which I would like to adjust the size of the font

```
@app.callback(
    Output('font_slider-output', 'style'),
    Input('font-slider', 'value'))

def update_output(value):
    """
    Font size slider prepared within 
    the accesibility tab 
    """

    font = [{'font-size' : '1rem'},
            {'font-size' : '1.5rem'},
            {'font-size' : '2rem'}]

    return font[value]
```

However I'm having trouble integrating this across all html items. I can get this to changes a single html.P but how can I adapt this to be used across items in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Target the `style` attribute of a primary Dash HTML `div` component containing your entire app layout contents to trigger global CSS changes via a callback

For example:

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    html.Div(
        [
            html.H1("Dash App - Slider to Increase Font Size"),
            dcc.Slider(
                min=0,
                max=2,
                step=1,
                value=0,
                marks={0: "Regular", 1: "Large", 2: "Larger"},
                id="font-slider",
            ),
            html.H2("Some Text Examples", id="text-1"),
            html.H3("This is some text.", id="text-2"),
            html.H4("This is some more text.", id="text-3"),
            html.P("This is yet more text.", id="text-4"),
        ],
        style={"width": "50%", "textAlign": "center", "margin": "auto"},
    ),
    id="main-div",
    style={"fontSize": "1rem"},
)


@app.callback(Output("main-div", "style"), [Input("font-slider", "value")])
def update_font_size(slider_value):
    font_sizes = ["1rem", "1.5rem", "2rem"]
    update_font_size = {x: y for x, y in zip(range(3), font_sizes)}
    return {"fontSize": update_font_size[slider_value]}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, dev_tools_hot_reload=True)
```

results in the following Dash app behavior:

[image: Video screenshot recording showing live Dash app with a slider that changes the size of all fonts within app layout]
You can see that all text elements (including `p` text but also all header text) are simultaneously increased in size.